# Is it possible to include other Python packages when packaging a Spacy model?

Tags: model, package, components, spacy

I'm trying to package a Spacy model that contains some custom language components and factories.

One of the components comes from the spacy_syllables python package (it also requires pyphen).

Is it possible to include packaged code when using the spacy package command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a partial `meta.json` with the additional `"requirements"` with `spacy package -m meta.json`: https://spacy.io/api/data-formats#meta